# How to enable confirmation alert before closing Cygwin window?

Tags: cygwin

I just closed a Cygwin window by means of an involuntary rogue mouse-click. A python script was running and it was about to complete its execution. So sad...

How do I enable any type of confirmation alert box option before closing an opened Cygwin window?

Do I need to configure something? I could not find any such options yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Mintty`, the default `Cygwin` terminal, has an option to ask confirmation before closing.

[image]

[image]